# How to test for an empty seq in Nim?

Tags: sequence, nim-lang

Let's say I have the following sequences:

```
var s1: seq[int] = @[]
var s2: seq[int]
var s3: seq[int] = nil
var s4: seq[int] = newSeq[int](4)
```

Which of these are typically considered "empty"? And what is the most idiomatic way to test if they are empty?

Right now I am just checking if `len` is `0`:

```
proc doSomething(s: seq[int]) =
  if s.len() == 0:
    echo("Your sequence is empty.")
  else:
    # do something
```

Comment: I think `s.len == 0` is pretty idiomatic. Note that it will work for `nil` seqs and empty seqs. You can also check for `nil` explicitly with `s.isNil`.

Comment: The empty ones are empty, so of course that's s1, s2, and s4, but not s3, because that doesn't even compile any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strutils module provides an `isNullOrEmpty` proc for strings: https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#isNilOrEmpty,string

As you can see in its implementation it just checks for `len(s) == 0`.

Comment: There's no longer any such proc because sequences can no longer be nil.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, sequences cannot be `nil`, so checking for length is sufficient.

For strings specifically, we also have [`isEmptyOrWhitespace`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#isEmptyOrWhitespace%2Cstring) if you also want to consider whitespace strings.